# Uploading a file (with weird format) to the Wolfram Cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I'd like to export `/path/to/api.trace` (the result of a GPU trace, which is in some weird format) to the Wolfram cloud (so that someone else can download it and inspect on their machine).  I've tried importing it as

```
Import[File["/path/to/api.trace"]]
Import[File["/path/to/api.trace"], "Text"]
```

but both fail to work. I either get

```
ToExpression::sntx: 
   Invalid syntax in or before "
      Import::infer: Cannot infer format of file api.trace.".
```

or

```
$Failed
```

Ultimately my goal is to feed it to

```
CopyFile[apiTrace, CloudObject["api.trace"]] (* Will this be downloadable? *)
```

How to get around this?

Comment: Hard to say without access to the file. Does it make any difference if you omit the `File` part and simply use the path in `Import`? It should not though. How big is the file? Is is text or binary? Anyway, perhaps if the only purpose is to share with someone else, then you could use a free account on e.g. DropBox or some similar service?

Comment: @MarcoB: It doesn't make a difference. It shows as `3144639` bytes large in my console. I guess it's in binary? I'd like to use Wolfram if I can because it's so much easier to use its REPL for one-off jobs like this (making throwaway links to files for temporary sharing, etc).

Comment: MarcoB: Using "Byte" instead of "Text" seems to work in `Import`, but I get errors when trying to use it in `CopyFile`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what exactly you tried (particularly, what is `apiTrace` in your code?), but just to clarify: In the first argument of `CopyFile`, you want the file name, not its contents. (If you want to deploy some given content to the cloud, use `CloudExport` or `CloudDeploy` or `CloudPublish`.)

So it should be as simple as

```
CopyFile["/path/to/api.trace", CloudObject["api.trace"]]
```

and then the file will probably be downloaded by default if you open the cloud object URL in a browser. (It depends on the browser what exactly will happen.)

You can always copy something from the cloud back to your local file system, e.g. using

```
CopyFile[CloudObject["api.trace"], "/some/other/path/to/api.trace"]
```

If you want to give others permission to view / download the file as well, give them "Read" permission, e.g.

```
SetPermissions[CloudObject["api.trace"], All->"Read"]
```

to make it publicly available (but you could also use a particular Wolfram ID instead of `All` to grant permissions to a particular user).

You can also use

```
Import[CloudObject["api.trace"], "Byte"]
```

(or, equivalently, `CloudImport["api.trace"], "Byte"]`) to import it back into Mathematica directly from the cloud.